# Ruby Non-gem dependencies

Tags: ruby, paperclip, external-dependencies

A gem I want to use called paperclip requires imagemagick to be installed. How can I get rails to manage these non-gem dependencies (for team/version controlled projects where you can't just ask everyone to install the dependencies for your feature).

I have been searching for an answer and cannot find an adequate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't. Paperclip execute command (like when you open your terminal), it doesn't use an API or a library for imagemagick.
So you can't manage your system with Rails, for that you have specific admin tools.

Or you can create a simple script for install this software but it's not very expendable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.